# I am having difficulty printing certain information from a __DATA__ source

Tags: perl, operators, expression

I am having difficulty printing just the zip code for Massachusetts for a home work assignment. The information is pulled from **DATA** and this can not be edited to make it easier.

I'm not asking for a direct answer just maybe some guidance of different methods this is my first programming language so I am still trying to understand. Thank you for your time.

I have been able to print the entire address successfully using the first section of code below.

I tried to split $address again by using the second section of code, but keep getting a fault for too many arguments for split at line 5. I've tried different formats of this code non of which are successful.

```
use warnings;
my ($name, $phone, $address, $Bday, $salary);
while (<DATA>){
($name, $phone, $address, $Bday, $salary) = split(":", $_);

print "$address\n" if $address =~ m/MA/g;

}

use warnings;
my ($name, $phone, $address, $Bday, $salary);
while (<DATA>){
($name, $phone, $address, $Bday, $salary) = split(":", $_);
($address) = split (",",$home,$town,$state,$zip);

print "$zip\n" if $address =~ m/MA/g;

}

__DATA__
Tommy Savage: 408-724-0140:122 Oxbow Court, Sunnyvale, CA 94087:5/19/66:34200
Lesle Kerstin: 408-456-1234:4 Harvard Square, Boston, MA 02133:4/22/62:52600
JonDeLoach: 408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 94086:7/25/53:85100
Ephram Hardy: 293-259-5395:235 Carlton Lane, Joliet, IL 73858:8/12/20:56700
Betty Boop: 245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
William Kopf: 846-836-2837:6937 Ware Road, Milton, PA 93756:9/21/46:43500
Norma Corder: 397-857-2753:74 Pine Street, Deadborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245700 
James Ikeda: 834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
Lori Gortz: 327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:35200
Barbara Kerz: 385-573-8326:832 Ponce Drive, Gary, IN 83756:12/15/46:268500
```

Output needs to just be the zip codes for MA

```
02133
34756
```

Comment: For starters, ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) takes two args. (Well, technically, up 3, but we just want the default for the third arg.) `split`'s first arg is a regex pattern on which to split. You have that right. `split`'s second arg is the value to split. That's the value of `$address`. That's it.

Comment: Tip: `if //g` makes no sense. Drop the `g`. Aside from making no sense, it will often work as if the `g` wasn't there as desired, but it will produce really weird results other times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message that you are getting indicates that you are not using `split` correctly. I guess that you actually meant:

```
($home,$town,$state,$zip) = split(",", $address);
```

instead of:

```
($address) = split (",",$home,$town,$state,$zip);
```

But fixing this will still not return the result you expect, mainly because the state and the zip code are not separated by a comma, but by a space. As your code is, `$zip` will end up undefined, while `$state` will contain both the state name and zip code.

Other considerations:

- always `use strict` and `use warnings`
- `split` usually takes a regular expression as first argument instead of a plain string ; also it takes `$_` as default argument, as many other perl built-ins.

Consider:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>){
    my $address = (split /:/)[2];
    if ($address =~ m/MA/g) {
        my ($zip) = ($address =~ /(\d+)$/);
        print "$zip\n";
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- since the adress is the only part that you need, don't capture the other parts; this avoids instantiating useless variables
- the zip code is made of a series of digits at the end of the adress

---

Here is a shorter syntax that just uses a single regular expression to parse the string, capture the relevant part and print it:

```
while (<DATA>){
    print "$1\n" if /^[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+MA (\d+):/;
}
```

Regexp explanation:

- `^` is the beginning of the string
- `[^:]+:` represents a group of as many characters as possible other than `:` (at least one), followed by `:`
- the third group of non-`:` characters should end with string `MA`, a space, and a series of digits; the parens around the digits indicates the this part of the string should be captured (it will then be available as `$1`)

Comment: OK, I think I get it, I was creating more work by capture a bunch of data that I didn't need. So you find the correct address using the if statement. Then my $zip is assigned to the numerical digits in those addresses?

Comment: @Derp: yes, exactly. Also see my updated answer for a shortest solution (although maybe a bit more complex).

Comment: The short solution is definitely more complex. Thank you very much for taking the time to help and explain this to me. It helped me realize what I was doing incorrectly. Cheers!

Comment: the `$_ =~` is unneeded.  but  far better to write code that doesn't use `$_`: `while (my $line = <DATA>) ... if $line =~ ...`

Comment: @ysth: yes I actually removed the `$_ =~` pretty much at the same time when you commented this... Thanks though !